# Reuse parts of a TFS build process template

Tags: tfs, build-automation

TFS build flow is defined in TFS 2010's build template(which in fact is Windows Workflow Foundation file with *.xaml extension).
It was pretty convenient for dealing with single build definition in simple project, but in the near future we'll have more complicated project where we'll have many very different build definitions, but in the same time some of them will have some significant common parts in logic.

And there is no wish to have common logic replicated in each build template, and on the other hand having one super-smart-parametrizable build is considered as not the best idea.

Long story short, but **the questions is**:
is there any possibility to put common logic into another build template/or_whatever and reuse it?

If not - do you have some approaches/recommendation regarding such situation?

**UPDATE**
As `K.Hoff` mentioned, there is a possibility to create custom activities, but I want to go deeper and reuse not only activities but sequences as well(put simply, similarly to like Ant or NAnt do - include one file into another, call one sequences from another, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to check whether it is possible to write code activity which executes workfow (.xaml file) with common build functionality. As a result such code activity could be put into several "master" build templates so it is possible to reuse common flow.
Here is an example how to dynamically load and execute workflow - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_introtowf_topic8.aspx.

Comment: Splendid! That's what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar situation, but since most of our build scenarios are similar (i.e. get->build->test->deploy) we have mostly solved it with one big definition and custom activities. **But** we also make use of the `ExecuteWorkflow` activity available from [Community TFS Build Extensions](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com).

This works well for "simple" scenarios, the reason we don't use this more extensively is because it's quite complicated to pass parameters between workflow executions. [Here's a link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sk/tfsbuild/thread/5b1ab1f3-4c4f-49b0-b03f-9f613c569b40) to a problem I had with this (and further down the solution I found).

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom code activities as explained [here](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2011/04/06/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-16-Specify-the-relative-reference-path.aspx) and reuse them in other build templates.

An other way is to implement good old msbuild scripts and put them in the msbuild execution activities to reuse them in many build process templates.

I can't find a quick way to reuse complete sequences, the only way we found is to write the acitvities as common as possible and inject parameters to get them run.

But I don't think it's a TFS problem it's a Workflow problem.

Comment: thanks for response. We've been already using custom activities for a long time. But what I'm asking about is reusing on much higher level; I mean sequences(forgot to clarify that in question; will do it)

Comment: btw, msbuild is considered by team as good good way, despite it's no so much "pretty" for us:)

Comment: I can understand this, for us too, but sometimes you need to get things work ;)

Comment: A custom activity can be created from XAML, can't it? Basically, copy from the current XAML file and paste into a new one, modify, etc.